# A question about semigroup union

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

The semigroup of all order-preserving and decreasing transformations in full transformations semigroup $T_n$ is denoted $C_n$.

I consider the idempotent set $A=\{\begin{bmatrix}2\\1  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\2  \end{bmatrix},\cdots, \begin{bmatrix}n\\n-1  \end{bmatrix}\}$.
It is well known that $\langle A \rangle = C_n$.

I want to determine smallest $k$ suct that  $C_n=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} A^k$

Comment: What is $T_n$? The set of upper triangular $n \times n$ matrices?

Comment: @Vincent I edited.

Comment: You can probably do an induction on defect (number of elements missing from the range) to get a good estimate and then try to find an element meeting the worst case.   It's at most $\binom{n}{2}$ by writing the Catalan monoid as a quotient of the 0-Hecke monoid but it is likely shorter.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the minimal number of generators needed to express any given transformation $f$ is $\sum_{i\in\operatorname{rng}(f)}(\max(f^{-1}(i))-i)$. This is maximized for the transformation $f(i)=\max(1,i-\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$, which gives $k=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thank you for comment. what is $rng(f)$.

Comment: The range of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}$For ease of notation, let me denote $a_i=\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{i+1}i$, so that $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$. I will write multiplication so that $(fg)(x)=f(g(x))$; reverse everything if you want the opposite convention.

> **Proposition:** For any $f\in C_n$, the least $k$ such that $f$ can be written in the form
>   $$f=a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\cdots a_{i_k}\tag1$$
>   for some $i_1,\dots,i_k\in[n-1]$ is
>   $$k=\sum_{y\in\im(f)}\bigl(\max(f^{-1}(y))-y\bigr).\tag2$$
>   Moreover, for each $i\in[n-1]$, the minimal number of occurrences of $a_i$ in (1) is
>   $$\bigl|\{y\in[n]:\exists x\in[n]\,(f(x)=y\le i<x)\}\bigr|.\tag3$$

**Proof:**

To prove the upper bound, let me fix $f\in C_n$ with image
$$\im(f)=\{y_1,\dots,y_l\},\qquad1=y_1<y_2<\dots<y_l\le n.$$
Putting $x_j=\max(f^{-1}(y_j))$, we have
$$1\le x_1<x_2<\dots<x_l=n,$$
and if we also define $x_0=0$, then for each $i\in[l]$:
$$f^{-1}(y_i)=[x_{i-1}+1,x_i].$$
In particular, $y_i\le x_{i-1}+1$. Now it remains to observe that
$$f=(a_{y_l}a_{y_l+1}\cdots a_{x_l-1})\cdots(a_{y_2}a_{y_2+1}\cdots a_{x_2-1})(a_{y_1}a_{y_1+1}\cdots a_{x_1-1}).$$

For the lower bound, assume $f$ is written as in (1), and let $i\in[n-1]$ and $x\in[n]$ be such that $f(x)\le i<x$. Then
$$x,a_{i_k}(x),(a_{i_{k-1}}a_{i_k})(x),\dots,(a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\cdots a_{i_k})(x)=f(x)$$
is a nonincreasing sequence which may decrease by at most $1$ at each step, hence there is a unique step where it goes from $i+1$ to $i$: that is, there is $j(x)\in[k]$ such that
$$(a_{i_{j(x)+1}}\cdots a_{i_k})(x)=i+1,\qquad (a_{i_{j(x)}}a_{i_{j(x)+1}}\cdots a_{i_k})(x)=i.$$
Clearly, we must have $i_{j(x)}=i$. Moreover, if $x'$ is such that $f(x')\le i<x'$, then
$$f(x)\ne f(x')\implies j(x)\ne j(x').\tag4$$
Indeed, if we had $j(x)=j(x')=j$, then
$$(a_{i_j}\cdots a_{i_k})(x)=(a_{i_j}\cdots a_{i_k})(x')=i,$$
hence
$$f(x)=(a_{i_1}\cdots a_{i_k})(x)=(a_{i_1}\cdots a_{i_{j-1}})(i)=(a_{i_1}\cdots a_{i_k})(x')=f(x').$$
Now, (4) implies that the number of occurrences of $a_i$ in (1) is at least (3). Summing over all $i$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
k&\ge\sum_i\bigl|\{y\le i:\exists x\in f^{-1}(y)\,(i<x)\}\bigr|\\
&=\bigl|\{(i,y):y\le i\land\exists x\in f^{-1}(y)\,(i<x)\}\bigr|\\
&=\sum_y\bigl|\{i:y\le i\land\exists x\in f^{-1}(y)\,(i<x)\}\bigr|\\
&=\sum_{y\in\im(f)}\bigl(\max(f^{-1}(y))-y\bigr),
\end{align*}$$
proving (2). QED

If $f\in C_n$ of image size $l$ is written as in the proof of the upper bound, (2) gives
$$k=\sum_{j=1}^l(x_j-y_j).$$
This expression is maximized (for a given $l$) when the $x_j$ are maximized, i.e., $x_j=n+j-l$, and $y_j$ are minimized, i.e., $y_j=j$. Thus,
$$k\le\sum_{j=1}^l(n+j-l-j)=l(n-l)\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor\lceil n/2\rceil=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor.$$
This bound is attained for the function $f(x)=\max(1,x-\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$. Thus:

> **Corollary:** The answer to the question is $k=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.

Comment: The preimage of $y_i$ under $f$ is the interval $[x_{i-1}+1,x_i]=\{x_{i-1}+1,\dots,x_i\}$.

Comment: I have no idea how you got to 4, but $\sum_{y\in\mathrm{im}(f)}(\max(f^{-1}(y))-y)$ is $3-1=2$ for $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$, $(2-1)+(3-2)=2$ for $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$, $(2-1)+(3-3)=1$ for $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&1&3\end{bmatrix}$, $(1-1)+(3-2)=1$ for $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&2\end{bmatrix}$, and $(1-1)+(2-2)+(3-3)=0$ for $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$. The maximum of these is $k=2$, which also agrees with the expression $k=\lfloor 3^2/4\rfloor$ I gave at the end.

Comment: Please read properly the statement of the Proposition instead of guessing. The expression $\sum_{y\in\mathrm{im}(f)}(\max(f^{-1}(y))-y)$, which as you can see depends on $f$, gives the minimum $k$ such that $f\in A^k$ for a *fixed function* $f\in C_n$. Let me denote it $k_f$. Then the minimum $k$ such that $C_n\subseteq\bigcup_{i\le k}A^k$ is $\max_{f\in C_n}k_f$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you advise me any paper the minimal number of generators needed to express any given transformation $f$ is $\sum_{i\in\operatorname{rng}(f)}(\max(f^{-1}(i))-i)$.

Comment: I don’t know of any paper. The proof I gave is fairly detailed, but if you have trouble following it, I suggest you ask at https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Thank you very much. Last question about the minimal number of occurrences of $a_i$ in (1) is $\bigl|\{y\in[n]:\exists x\in[n]\,(f(x)=y\le i<x)\}\bigr|$. I can' t understand well this. For example  how did you calculate it for $C_3$?

Comment: This is again a bound for a specific function $f$, not for the whole $C_n$. Moreover, there isn’t much to see for $C_3$-functions, as they are too simple. Let me take an example $f=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\1&1&1&2&2\end{bmatrix}\in C_5$. For $i=2$, the pairs $(x,y=f(x))$ that cross the gap $(3,2)$ are $(5,2)$, $(4,2)$, and $(3,1)$. Among these, there are 2 distinct values of $y$ (viz. $1$ and $2$), hence the expression gives 2, i.e., whever we write this $f$ as a product of elements of $A$, we have to use $a_2$ at least twice. Likewise, we have to use each of $a_1,a_3,a_4$ at least once. ...

Comment: ... These bounds are tight, as we can write $f=a_2a_3a_4a_1a_2$.

Comment: I understand in your example. we have to use $a_2$ at least twice. Because of $i=2$ and $2$ distinct values of $y$. How can you understand we have to use each of $a_1,a_3,a_4$ at least once.

Comment: why we use transformation $f(i)=\max(1,i-\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$.

Comment: I am sorry but I have no time to coach you through this line by line. I repeat the suggestion to take further questions to math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Thank you for everything.  Last question about this question. Why and where we use the transformation $f(i)=\max(1,i-\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$

Comment: To find the worst possible value of $k$.

Comment: $x_j=n+j-l$ is not true for example $f=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\1&1&1&2&2\end{bmatrix}\in C_5$.In here $x_1=3$, but  $x_1=n+j-l=5+1-2=4$. Do I overlook some detail proof ?

Comment: This $f$ does not achieve the maximal value of $k$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I couldn't understand the last step and why $ x_j=n+j-l$. How can you say equality $l(n-l)\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor\lceil n/2\rceil=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor.$ Can you advise to me any book ort article to more undesrtand concept?

Comment: I’m sorry but I have no time to explain these trivialities to you. I told you multiple times to take further questions to https://math.stackexchange.com .